# Making an editable dropdown and populating it from an external JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an editable dropdown, and on double click of the data the dropdown should appear and make populate the options from and external JS, this should be made to run more than once. 
The following is the HTML for this

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <table id='table-draggable1'>
                <tbody class="connectedSortable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>col1</th>
                        <th>col2</th>
                        <th>col3</th>
                        <th>col4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>156</td>
                        <td>668</td>
                        <td>100.95</td>
                        <td class="master">100.95</td> //editable dropdown
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desc">256</td>
                        <td>668</td>
                        <td>100.95</td>
                        <td class="master">100.95</td> // ondblclick should be editable
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery which i tried for making the dropdown editable

```
    $document.ready(function ()
        {
dropdown();
            $(function ()
            {
                $(".master").dblclick(function (e)
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var currentEle = $(e.target);
                    var value = $(e.target).html();
                    console.log($(e.target));
                    if ($.trim(value) === "")
                    {
                        $(currentEle).data('mode', 'add');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(currentEle).data('mode', 'edit');
                    }
                    updateVal(currentEle, value);
                });
            });

            function updateVal(currentEle, value)
            {
                $(currentEle).html("<select class='master'></select>");
                var mode = $(currentEle).data('mode');
                alert(mode);
                $(".master").focus();
                $(".master").keyup(function (event)
                {
                    if (event.keyCode == 13)
                    {
                        $(this).parent().html($(this).val().trim());
                        $(".master").remove();
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).click(function (e)
            {
                if ($(".master") !== undefined)
                {
                    if ($(".master").val() !== undefined)
                    {
                        $(".master").parent().html($(".master").val().trim());
                        $(".master").remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function dropdown()
        {
           var resp = "<option>" + 1 + "</option>"; //this should be populated in dropdown
           $(".master").html(resp);
        }
    }

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tXakG/

Comment: Try $(document) instead of $document

Comment: No sir. It doesn't work. I have tried everything. Its not the syntax errors. The dropdown should be populated from the backend. So on double click the dropdown should appear and all the options should be populated.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the datalist tag in HTML5.

```
<input type="text" name="product" list="productName"/>
<datalist id="productName">
    <option value="a">Apple</option>
    <option value="o">Orange</option>
    <option value="b">Banana</option>
</datalist>
```

If you double click on the input text in the browser a list with the defined option will appear.

Added using javascript : data is conceded that taken from server through ajax

http://jsfiddle.net/rajaveld/7yM6V/

Else you can use jquery :

You can refer is [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for the same.

Comment: I need to get the options from the backend, so their is no defined list of options for this. So on click or double click it should make the text box editable and the list of options should be populated

Comment: ya i can understood, for that you can use ajax to get the data and create this datalist in javascript

Comment: I got the data populated, but when i try editing the list is not populated.

Comment: If its possible try giving a fiddle. I have tried the solution u are trying to give. But it is not working . i have used javascript to populate the ui , using jquery i have made other text fields editabble but i am not able to get the dropdown.

Comment: Which is not working? you cant get data from database?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N2tfN/. .i figured that out. can u help me with the last thing. in this after i choose a date and drop down it shud update. but it remains in the same thing. i want it to update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57158/discussion-between-cerebus1504-and-rajavel-d).